# How do I map an array and change the color of the text of just the item I tap on using React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native

How do I change the color of a single item from a mapped array? My code below will change the color of all the items in the array to green. I want just the item I tap on to turn green. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';

const PickNotesToTranspose = () => {

    const chromaticArrChoose = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#/Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#/Gb', 'G', 'G#/Ab', 'A', 'A#/Bb', 'B'];
    const [isPressed, setIsPressed] = useState(false);

  

    const mapArrChoose = chromaticArrChoose.map((c, index) => {
        const handlePress = () => {
            isPressed ? setIsPressed(false): setIsPressed(true);
        
        }

        return (
            <Pressable key={index} onPress={() => handlePress()}>
                <Text style={[isPressed? styles.selectedNote: styles.chromatic]}>{c}</Text>
            </Pressable>
        )
    })
    return (
        <Text>{mapArrChoose}</Text>
    )
}


export default PickNotesToTranspose;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    chromatic: {
        fontSize: 32,

    },
    btnStyle: {
        borderWidth: 1,
    },

    chooseKeyTxt: {
        marginTop: 50,
        fontSize: 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
    },

    selectedNote: {
        color: 'green',
        fontSize: 32,

    },


})
```

Comment: Can multiple items be green at the same time if you tap of multiple, or should it switch which one is green?

Comment: Yes multiple items can be green at the same time. This is very helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You should save pressed states in object or array variable.
For example, refer below codes.

```js
import { Text, StyleSheet, View, Pressable } from 'react-native';
import { useState } from 'react';

const PickNotesToTranspose = () => {

    const chromaticArrChoose = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#/Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#/Gb', 'G', 'G#/Ab', 'A', 'A#/Bb', 'B'];
    const [pressedState, setPressedState] = useState({});

  

    const mapArrChoose = chromaticArrChoose.map((c, index) => {
        const handlePress = () => {
            const isPressed = pressedState[index];
            setPressedState((values) => ({
                ...values,
                [index]: isPressed ? true : false,
            }));
        }

        return (
            <Pressable key={index} onPress={() => handlePress()}>
                <Text style={[pressedState[index]? styles.selectedNote: styles.chromatic]}>{c}</Text>
            </Pressable>
        )
    })
    return (
        <Text>{mapArrChoose}</Text>
    )
}
```

Wishing this could help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have created a common sharing state and every item of JSX is pointing or looking the value of pressed at same place.

You can create an state of all item and then use that state to get value of pressed as:

```
const PickNotesToTranspose = () => {

    const chromaticArrChoose = ['C', 'C#', 'D', 'D#/Eb', 'E', 'F', 'F#/Gb', 'G', 'G#/Ab', 'A', 'A#/Bb', 'B'];

    // CHANGE
    const [pressed, setPressed] = useState(() => chromaticArrChoose.reduce((acc, curr) => ({ ...acc, [curr]: false }), {}));

  

    const mapArrChoose = chromaticArrChoose.map((c, index) => {
        const handlePress = () => {

            // CHANGE
            setPressed(state => ({ ...state, [c]: !state[c]}))
        }

        return (
            <Pressable key={index} onPress={() => handlePress()}>

                // CHANGE
                <Text style={[pressed[c]? styles.selectedNote: styles.chromatic]}>{c}</Text>
            </Pressable>
        )
    })
    return (
        <Text>{mapArrChoose}</Text>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. This works however I don't quite understand how it is working. Can you explain what the line  chromaticArrChoose.reduce... is actually doing. I understand reduce when used with numbers to sum an array but am confused how it is working in this instance. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Tony `chromaticArrChoose.reduce...` will create an object of `key` as `chromaticArrChoose` and value as initially `false` and then later when you press a text then it will only invert it based on the `key`

Comment: @Tony Take the latest code. Made some changes